# Updating SQLite database with particular values for multiple WHERE clauses

Tags: android, sql, list, sql-update, keyvaluepair

I need to update my database with the `List` where the name of each element is the `WHERE` clause and the value is the new value to be written to the row which satisfies the `WHERE` clause. But all the `WHERE` clauses are different and have different values. To make it clearer I will give an example:

`"robin":"25"
"charles":"31"
"megan":"27"`

The names (robin, charles, megan) are the `WHERE` clauses and the numbers (25, 31, 27) are the values. So how to efficiently update my `SQLite` database with these values?

Now I am using this algorithm, but I believe it causes a huge overhead for the system:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
for (int i = 0; i < counts.size(); i++) {
    values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.MyTable.COLUMN_NAME_NUMBER, counts.get(i).getValue());
    String whereClause = MyDatabaseHelper.MyTable.COLUMN_NAME_NAME
            + " = " + counts.get(i).getName();
    rowsAffected += db.update(MyDatabaseHelper.MyTable.TABLE_NAME,
            values, whereClause, null);
}
```

where `counts` is my `List<NameValuePair>` object.

Comment: Can you elaborate `The names (robin, charles, megan) are the WHERE clauses and the numbers (25, 31, 27) are the values.`?

Comment: Looks at the syntax of `SQLiteDatabase` `update()` method and you should understand what I mean http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html. The names are the arguments for the `WHERE` clause, for example: UPDATE ... WHERE COLUMN_NAME_NAME = robin...

Comment: I mean `UPDATE MyDatabaseHelper.MyTable.TABLE_NAME SET MyDatabaseHelper.MyTable.COLUMN_NAME_NUMBER = [value from the list] WHERE MyDatabaseHelper.MyTable.COLUMN_NAME_NAME = [name from the list]`. I want to set the new values for the rows in the database that satisfies the `WHERE` clause, but doing it from a loop is inefficient in my opinion, but I can't see any other solution, because each `name` from the list is different (it means different `WHERE` clause) and has different `value`, so I am asking for your help.

Comment: So, `If COLUMN_NAME_NAME = 'robin' then COLUMN_NAME_NUMBER = 25, If If COLUMN_NAME_NAME = 'charles' then COLUMN_NAME_NUMBER = 31 and If COLUMN_NAME_NAME = 'megan' then COLUMN_NAME_NUMBER = 27`?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean!

Comment: There might be the possibility to do so in a unique command, but it I suspect it would be **very inefficient**. Better use 3 separate update commands.

Comment: You mean the loop, right?